# find: missing argument to -exec when run from file but not from cli

Tags: sh, ubuntu-14.04, command-line-interface

I have a file that looks like this

```
#!/bin/bash

find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find . -type f -exec chown vagrant:www-data {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chown vagrant:www-data {} \;
```

let's assume it's called `foo.sh`
I'm on an Ubuntu 14.04 machine and i have root rights `sudo su` before I execute it.

If I call `sh foo.sh` the command line tells me:

```
# sh foo.sh 
: not foundh: 2: foo.sh: 
find: missing argument to `-exec'
find: missing argument to `-exec'
find: missing argument to `-exec'
find: missing argument to `-exec'
: not foundh: 7: foo.sh:
```

but when I run the 4 commands after each other directly from the command line, well then it works. Here's the question: What's wrong? And why is it complaining about line 2 and 7 (they are empty)

Thanks (:

Comment: Check for line endings. You did not happen to edit this shell script under windows, did you?

Comment: As I recall, I didn't but it would be possible. How can I check the line endings? I use NetBeans as editor while on a GUI and otherwise nano when using the CLI. Can I check that with them?

Comment: I'm not using either of those but this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986421/how-do-i-switch-between-windows-and-unix-newlines-in-netbeans

Comment: Thanks for your help (: I was able to fix it and put it as an solution below, if anyone runs in the same problem, as I did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to the help of [@fejese](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1565862/fejese) I managed to fix it.

The problem was that the files had Windows/DOS line endings. Not sure why, maybe I have opened it once on my windows machine. More important then the how did it happen is the how can I fix it to me.

first find out what file endings are used. Therefore we can use the command line:

```
file foo.sh
```

If this outputs something like:

```
foo.sh: Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable, with CRLF line terminators
```

If you have the `CRLF line terminators` stuff, then you have to fix it with the `dos2unix` program.

```
sudo apt-get install dos2unix
dos2unix foo.sh
file foo.sh
```

**you only have to run the apt-get stuff (first line) if you don't have dos2unix installed yet.**
Now it should look something like this:

```
foo.sh: Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable
```

And now you can run it without any problem using

```
sh foo.sh
```

Further reading about file, dos2unix and unix2dos you can find here: [View line-endings in a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569997/view-line-endings-in-a-text-file)

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to installing `dos2unix`:

```
sed -i -e "s/\r//g" foo.sh
```

This command replaces all `\r` characters in the file in-place.

Comment: Seams to work as well. I personally prefer the dos2unix solution, because it's easier to remember and if there would be a change in line endings (I know, wont happen :P), the dos2unix will probably get updated, so we don't have to change anything ;)

Comment: Me too, but sometimes it's not possible or preferable not to install packages for a simple job like this.

Comment: Yet again a down vote without any suggestion why it's not a good answer.